# Can't set values to model using Angular material

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to get data from back-end service to my angular material model. But I can't set response data to my html components.

This is my angular code.

```
   $scope.assignDataById = [];
    var method = "GET";
    var url = 'users/get_list_by_epf/' + Epf;




    $scope.createUserBusy = $http({
        method: method,
        url: url,



       headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        transformResponse: [
            function (data) {
                $scope.assignDataById.push(data);



           }
        ]



   });
    console.log($scope.assignDataById);
```

Comment: Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking questions and improve your question with more details.